# CComboBoxEx: Hide the image of an item when it is being displayed in the combobox edit component

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, mfc

Is it possible to have `CComboBoxEx` NOT display the image of the selected item inside the `CEdit` part, even though the selected item has an image which shows when the drop-down list is visible?

I can't seem to find a way to do this and was wondering if it is even possible with `CComboBoxEx`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of an easy solution without subclassing or dealing with `WM_PAINT` messages. 
If you look at the `ComboBoxEx` control with SPY++, you will notice that the icon is part of the ComboBox even when the combo box is closed.

Still, you can control the selected image of the item by registering to `CBN_DROPDOWN` and `CBN_CLOSEUP` notification messages that are sent to your parent window (usually the dialog).

The general idea is to set the selected image index to -1 when the combo box is closed.

This code assumes that the item index is also the index of the image in the image list.

```
// CBN_DROPDOWN-> called when the combo is opened. Need to set 
// the selected image.
void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnCbnDropdownComboboxex1()
{
    int i = m_combo.GetCurSel();
    if (i > CB_ERR)
    {
        COMBOBOXEXITEM cmbItem = { 0 };
        CString strText;
        cmbItem.iItem = i;
        cmbItem.mask = CBEIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;
        m_combo.GetItem(&cmbItem);
        cmbItem.iSelectedImage = i;
        m_combo.SetItem(&cmbItem);
    }
}

// CBN_DROPDOWN -> called when the combo is closed. Need to 
// set the selected image to -1.
void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnCbnCloseupComboboxex1()
{
    int i = m_combo.GetCurSel();
    if (i > CB_ERR)
    {
        COMBOBOXEXITEM cmbItem = { 0 };
        CString strText;            
        cmbItem.iItem = i;
        cmbItem.mask = CBEIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;

        m_combo.GetItem(&cmbItem);      

        cmbItem.iSelectedImage = -1;
        m_combo.SetItem(&cmbItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP knows how to assign images to combo box items. That's not the question, though. The question is whether it is possible to have images in the drop-down list, but not display the image in the embedded edit control once the drop-down list has collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do much here. ComboBoxEx is actually implemented in Win32 as a ComboBox subclass, performing owner-draw actions. This alone makes things harder. Therefore I can think of two possible solutions.

First, check if you can capture the `WM_DRAWITEM` message (and it is actually being called), and if you can differntiate between calls for an item in the list and the "edit" part. If so you, you could perform a custom draw for the edit part, and call the default for the items in the list. There are two messages, `CBEM_GETCOMBOCONTROL` and `CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL` (`GetComboBoxCtrl()` and `GetEditCtrl()` in `CComboBoxEx` of MFC), which you can check out, although I don't know if and what you can modify there. The edit-control is not available in the case of drop-down-list combo-boxes.

Another possible "solution" (rather a workaround) could be to place an edit (in the drop-down case) or static (in the drop-list case) control on top of the edit part of the combo box (that is cover it). Use the clip children style to ensure proper painting. You will need to write some little code to synchronize the two controls, eg update the static control when the selected item in the list changes. The drop-down (?) control for the fonts in Excel for example, seems to employ such a technique. It's a rich-edit control actually (checked it with Spy++). Last resort (and a really simple one), a blank static control (without any text), just covering the image in the edit part.

Also take a look in the `CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH` message. Not sure if it can be used in ComboBoxEx controls (it's for normal combo-boxes), but as ComboBoxEx is a subclass, it may work as well.